# Como integrar Miscrosoft Graph api a swiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, graph

estoy tratando de integrar Microsoft Graph api a swiftUI pero realmente no encuentro la manera. Ya revisé en muchos otros lugares de internet, incluyendo foros en ingles y ninguno de ellos termina dando algo útil.
Lo más útil que encontré es este video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lnfa55NNtXg&t=184s&ab_channel=FabioCirruto
Pero la info.plist de él y la mía son diferentes.

```
import SwiftUI
import MSAL

class MicrosoftLoginController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: self.view.frame.height - 100, width: self.view.frame.width - 40, height: 52))
        btn.backgroundColor = .orange
        btn.setTitle("Acces", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
    }
    @objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        do {
            let authority = try MSALB2CAuthority(url: URL(string: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common")!)
            
            let pcaConfig = MSALPublicClientApplicationConfig(clientId: "da176e3b-------------", redirectUri: nil,authority: authority)
            
            let application = try MSALPublicClientApplication(configuration: pcaConfig)
            let webViewParameters = MSALWebviewParameters(authPresentationViewController: self)
            let interactiveParameters = MSALInteractiveTokenParameters(scopes: ["user.read"], webviewParameters: webViewParameters)
            
            application.acquireToken(with: interactiveParameters) { (result, error) in
                
                guard let result = result else {
                    print(error!)
                    return }
                
                if let account = result.account.username {
                    print(account)
                    UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }!.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
struct MyCustomLogin: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = MicrosoftLoginController
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MyCustomLogin>) -> MicrosoftLoginController {
        return MicrosoftLoginController()
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MicrosoftLoginController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

El código es el mismo que el del video, la única diferencia es la info.plist, la mía se ve de esta manera:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict/>
</plist>
```

Si alguien sabe algo le pido por favor que deje algún ejemplo, soy nuevo en programación y todo me cuesta bastante. Gracias

Comment: Puedes detallar mejor sobre el error que tienes?

Comment: El problema es que mi info.plist no es la misma que la del video en el minuto 2:53, teniendo en cuenta que los dos proyectos se arrancan de 0 supongo que las capetas info.plist deberían ser iguales, pero no es lo que pasa. Quisiera saber si no estoy entendiendo algo o simplemente copiando la info.plist del video podré continuar. Gracias. @Bicho

Comment: Los valores que se agregan en el `info.plist` son importantes para que funcione bien una app. Las nuevas versiones de Xcode generan diferentes archivos `.plist` por eso puede ser que no es el mismo al del video.